# How do I calculate and display win/loss for two different teams in Java using a boolean function and arrays

Tags: java, arrays, function, boolean

I am still new to Java and have an assignment that I am stuck on. I believe I got the boolean function correct, however I cannot figure out what to write in the main function.

This the assignment:
Write a public function (static method) winner(int points1,int points2) that takes two scores and returns a boolean. If points1 is greater than points2 the function returns true and if points1 is less than points2, the function returns false. Points should not be tied but return false if that ever happens. The function returns false if none of the conditions is true.

In your main function, create two arrays -the first array is team 1’s points and the second array is opponents’ points in corresponding games, i.e., the first items in the arrays are the scores for each team in the first game and so on. The arrays are the same length.

Using the function winner from above, calculate and print the win/loss record of team1. If all games were won, print out a message saying that team1 has a perfect record. Here are some examples:

Team1 Points
{23,45,65,20}

Opponent Points
{56,67,20,18}

This is what teamRecord should print:

### Team1 Record

Win 2
Loss 2

My code so far

```
import java.util.*;
public class TeamScore {

public static boolean createWinner(int points1, int points2)  
 {
  if (points1 > points2)
  {
  return true;
  }
        else
 {
  return false;  
 } 
 }
public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] team1Array = new int[4];
int[] team2Array = new int[4];
int result1 = 0; 
int result2 = 0; 
int team1Score;
int team2Score;
int win;
int loss;


 System.out.println("Enter Team 1 points: ");
 team1Score = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
 System.out.println("Enter Team 2 points: ");
 team2Score = Integer.parseInt (in.nextLine()); 

 for (int i=0; i <team1Array.length; i++)

 {

  createWinner(points1);

 }


  System.out.println("Win"+ team1Score);
  //System.out.println(result2+"");
}






}
```

Comment: Please do not edit your question to remove important content from it. That is entirely unfair to those who have spent time and effort answering your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of issues in your code :

1) You declared a function  `createWinner(int points1, int points2)`  , but in your main you call `createWinner(points1)`

2) In your main, what's `points1`? You didn't declare it.

3) Before computing, you should populate your arrays

After this explanation, you can modify your code with following :

```
        import java.util.*;
        public class TeamScore {

        public static boolean createWinner(int points1, int points2)  
         {
          if (points1 > points2)
          {
          return true;
          }
                else
         {
          return false;  
         } 

         return false;
         }
        public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] team1Array = new int[4];
        int[] team2Array = new int[4];

        int team1Score = 0;
        int team2Score = 0;


        for (int i =0; i<4; i++) {
     System.out.println("Enter Team 1 points: ");
             team1Array[i]= Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Enter Team 2 points: ");
             team2Array[i] = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        }




         for (int i=0; i <4; i++)

         {

        if (createWinner(team1Array[i],team2Array[1])) {
           team1Score+=1;
       } else {
           team2Score+=1;
       }

         }


  if(team1Score>0 && team2Score == 0){
        System.out.println("Team 1 has perfect record !");
    }else{
          System.out.println("Win "+ team1Score);

          System.out.println("Loss "+ team2Score);

        }





        }
}
```

Less or more should work (I didn't try).

Comment: The signature of a function  must be always the same, thus if you define `function(int a, int b)`, in your main (or everywhere) you must call `function(int,int)`.

Comment: Good point! You're solution was correct. Must have clicked his by mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take the input from user 4 times and store it in an array using for loop:

```
for (int i =0; i<4; i++) {
     team1Array[i]= //take user input for team1
     team2Array[i] = //take user input for team2
}
```

Then you could loop over array and increase individual score like:

```
for (int i=0; i <team1Array.length; i++) {
   if (createWinner(points1)) {
       //increment team1Score;
   } else {
       //increment team2Score;
   }
}
```

Compare individual score using if and announce the winner by printing onto console.